# как из скрипта автоматом отдавать ссылку в input value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Допустим есть скрипт который генерирует конечные ссылки с парметрами, но генерирует ссылку только при клике на кнопку, как автоматом генерировать ссылки в поле инпут с отдачей всех отдаевымых параметров скриптом?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setlink ( offer, flow ) {
        $("#offer"+offer+"flow").val( flow );
        setflow( offer );
        $("#link"+offer).show();
        return false;

    }

    function setflow ( offer ) {
        var flow = $("#offer"+offer+"flow").val();
        $("#offer"+offer+"land").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-site") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"space").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-space") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"subcmp").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-subcmp") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"fb").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-fb") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"vk").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-vk") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"yd").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-yd") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"gg").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-gg") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"tt").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-tt") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"my").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-my") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"url").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-url") );
        $("#offer"+offer+"pbu").val( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-pbu") );
        $("#usecomeback"+offer).prop( "checked", $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-cb") == 1 ? true : false )
        $("#usesimple"+offer).prop( "checked", $("#flowdata"+flow).attr("data-param") == 1 ? true : false )

        makelink( offer );
        return false;

    }

    function makelink ( offer ) {

        var usecb = $("#usecomeback"+offer).prop( "checked" ) ? 1 : 1;
        var usesm = $("#usesimple"+offer).prop( "checked" ) ? 1 : 1;
        var flsep = usesm ? "/?flow=" : "/?";
        var flow  = $("#offer"+offer+"flow").val();
        var landi = $("#offer"+offer+"land").val();
        var landn = $("#offer"+offer+"land"+landi).text();
        var spaci = parseInt( $("#offer"+offer+"space").val() );
        var spacn = $("#offer"+offer+"space"+spaci).text();
        var subcmp    = $("#offer"+offer+"subcmp").val();
        var fb    = $("#offer"+offer+"fb").val();
        var vk    = $("#offer"+offer+"vk").val();
        var yd    = $("#offer"+offer+"yd").val();
        var gg    = $("#offer"+offer+"gg").val();
        var tt    = $("#offer"+offer+"tt").val();
        var my    = $("#offer"+offer+"my").val();
        var tburl = $("#offer"+offer+"url").val();
        var pburl = $("#offer"+offer+"pbu").val();
        var redmn = $("#offer"+offer+"redmn").val();
        var targt = $("#offer"+offer+"targt").val();
        var url = "https://";

        if ( typeof(redmn) == "undefined" || redmn == "" || redmn == "0" ) {
            if ( tburl == "" ) {
                if ( spaci > 0 ) {
                    url += spacn + flsep + flow + "-" + landi;
                    var cr = $("#offer"+offer+"space"+spaci).attr( "data-cr" );
                    var epc = $("#offer"+offer+"space"+spaci).attr( "data-epc" );
                } else {                    url += landn + flsep + flow;
                    var cr = $("#offer"+offer+"land"+landi).attr( "data-cr" );
                    var epc = $("#offer"+offer+"land"+landi).attr( "data-epc" );
                }
                if ( usecb ) url += "&cb";
                } else url = "{flow_rd}go"+flow;
        } else url = "http://"+redmn+"/go"+flow;

        if ( typeof(subcmp) != "undefined" && subcmp != "" && subcmp != "0" ) {
            url = url + ( ( url.indexOf('?') === -1 ) ? '?' : '&' ) + 'subcmp=' + subcmp;
        }
        
        if ( typeof(fb) != "undefined" && fb != "" && fb != "0" ) {
            url = url + ( ( url.indexOf('?') === -1 ) ? '?' : '&' ) + 'fb=' + fb;
        }

       if ( typeof(vk) != "undefined" && vk != "" && vk != "0" ) {
            url = url + ( ( url.indexOf('?') === -1 ) ? '?' : '&' ) + 'vk=' + vk;
        }
        
            if ( typeof(yd) != "undefined" && yd != "" && yd != "0" ) {
            url = url + ( ( url.indexOf('?') === -1 ) ? '?' : '&' ) + 'yd=' + yd;
        }
        
            if ( typeof(gg) != "undefined" && gg != "" && gg != "0" ) {
            url = url + ( ( url.indexOf('?') === -1 ) ? '?' : '&' ) + 'gg=' + gg;
        }
        
            if ( typeof(tt) != "undefined" && tt != "" && tt != "0" ) {
            url = url + ( ( url.indexOf('?') === -1 ) ? '?' : '&' ) + 'tt=' + tt;
        }
        
                if ( typeof(my) != "undefined" && my != "" && my != "0" ) {
            url = url + ( ( url.indexOf('?') === -1 ) ? '?' : '&' ) + 'my=' + my;
        }


        $("#offer"+offer+"link").val( url );
        $("#offer"+offer+"cr").text( cr );
        $("#offer"+offer+"epc").text( epc );

        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-site" ) != landi )     flowchange ( flow, 'site',  landi );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-space" ) != spaci )    flowchange ( flow, 'space', spaci );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-cb" ) != usecb )       flowchange ( flow, 'cb',    usecb );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-param" ) != usesm )    flowchange ( flow, 'param', usesm );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-subcmp" ) != subcmp )  flowchange ( flow, 'subcmp', subcmp );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-fb" ) != fb )          flowchange ( flow, 'fb', fb );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-vk" ) != vk )          flowchange ( flow, 'vk', vk );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-yd" ) != yd )          flowchange ( flow, 'yd',    yd );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-gg" ) != gg )          flowchange ( flow, 'gg', gg );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-tt" ) != tt )          flowchange ( flow, 'tt',    tt );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-my" ) != my )          flowchange ( flow, 'my',    my );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-url" ) != tburl )      flowchange ( flow, 'url',   tburl );
        if ( $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-pbu" ) != pburl )      flowchange ( flow, 'pbu',   pburl );

    }

    function loadtargets ( offer ) {        $("#targets"+offer).load( "{flow_tgt}" + offer );
    }



    function flowchange ( flow, param, value ) {        $("#flowdata"+flow).attr( "data-"+param, value );
        $.get( "{flow_ajax}"+flow+"?"+param+"="+escape(value) );
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `#('button').on('click', function(){  тут вызов вашей функции генерации линка и вставки в input})`

Comment: а как без клика генерировать? автоматически?

Comment: реально не понятен смысл задачи. если у вас уже всё на странице и вопрос только в том, чтобы вызвать исполнение некоторой функции не по клику а иначе? ну, вызовите её по таймеру setTimeout()

Comment: Либо window.onload/DOMContentLoaded для выполнения кода после загрузки всей страницы/после построения DOM дерева.